# How to enable multiple bitbuttons?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010

I would like to know how to enable 10 bitbuttons via code without `bitbtn1.enable := true' for each one.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
for a:= 1 to 10 do
  begin
   bitbtn+inttostr(a).enabled:=true; 

   end;
```

How can I fix this, or is there another method?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many options.

If the buttons all have the same parent control and you want to adjust *all* `TBitBtn` child controls of this parent, you can simply iterate over the parent's child controls:

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
    if Controls[i] is TBitBtn then
      TBitBtn(Controls[i]).Enabled := True;
```

(In this case, the parent is `Self` assuming it exists. For instance, this could be a method in your form class. Explicitly, this is

```
  for i := 0 to Self.ControlCount - 1 do
    if Self.Controls[i] is TBitBtn then
      TBitBtn(Self.Controls[i]).Enabled := True;
```

If the parent is `Panel1` instead, you do

```
  for i := 0 to Panel1.ControlCount - 1 do
    if Panel1.Controls[i] is TBitBtn then
      TBitBtn(Panel1.Controls[i]).Enabled := True;
```

)

If you only want to adjust some of these, you can for instance give them a `Tag = 1` to distinguish them from other bit buttons:

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
    if Controls[i] is TBitBtn then
      if TBitBtn(Controls[i]).Tag = 1 then
        TBitBtn(Controls[i]).Enabled := True;
```

If they don't all have the same parent, it is slightly more tricky. One option is to create an array (a private field of the form class, say) with all your buttons at application startup:

```
private
  FButtons: TArray<TBitBtn>;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FButtons := [BitBtn1, BitBtn2, BitBtn3];
end;
```

Then you can simply iterate over this one:

```
var
  Btn: TBitBtn;
begin
  for Btn in FButtons do
    Btn.Enabled := True;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this `bitbtn+inttostr(a).enabled:=true` but you **can** do `FindComponent('bitbtn'+inttostr(a)).enabled := true`.

Though I do recommend you to put them all inside a panel and set `panel.enabled := true`. As it would be much faster and simple.

Comment: This is also a good approach, but a bit fragile. If you rename the component at design time, you will not notice the newly created bug at compile time.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend against the panel-based approach, since the buttons will then not look disabled. The user will think the application has frosen.

Comment: Just don't use this approach in a large commercial application, please! :)

Comment: Yeah, @Fuzail, @Andreas Rejbrand is right. That said, you could then make use of a validation, or something like that, so the application would not crash. And for the appearance thing, you could use the approach @Andreas brought, with the `ControlCount`.